# Java replace all regex matches

Tags: java, regex

I have `htmlBody` field which has html of a web page assigned to it. I want to check for all occurences for relative links ending in `.html` and for each of them to remove their extension. I do not want `htmlBody.replaceAll(".html", "")` because it will remove for all links and break some external links so my approach is to find all occurences that matches regex, and for each occurence to remove their extension using `replaceAll()` and append to `sb`. I tried to follow the example from official documentation but apparently it does not change any link, what could be the problem?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\/(.+\\\\)*(.+).(html)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlBody);

while (m.find()) {
  String updatedLink = m.group().replaceAll(".html", "");
  m.appendReplacement(sb, updatedLink);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

Comment: `replaceAll` accepts regex as its first parameter.  `.` has a special meaning in `regex.  Use `replace` instead as it does the same but does not accept regex as its first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

your regex was wrong, ^ match start of string, $ match end of string.
so matcher in your code will never match.

right regex like `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("['\"]\\/(.+\\\\)*(.+).(html)");`
but, it can't match `<a href=/a.html>`

Comment: and, your regex can't match `<a href="a.html">`  because you want the link start with '\'